# iPhone UIScrollview: Button does not respond when located below 480 pixels on Scroll View's child UIView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have built a view for an iPhone app in Interface Builder. It is a UIScrollview with a UIView and a UIButton on the UIView. The only code I have is setting the scroll view's contentSize to 320x550 in the viewDidLoad method of the xib's File Owner class. When the button is within the normal view area (320x480) the button responds as normal, but if is placed outside of those boundaries in Interface Builder the button will not respond when I scroll to it and click the button.

What am I missing? I figure it might be something I need to set on the UIView. But I am not sure what that is.

Answer (score 6):

Your UIButton won't response even it's visible because it's not in the boundary of parent view. You can see object outside the boundary of its parent view because it's a default behavior of UIView to draw all subview (clipsToBounds = NO)

To see the truth, try this code.

```
UIView *yourUIView = ...
yourUIView.clipsToBounds = YES;
yourUIView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
```

You will no longer see your UIButton.

**To fix this, enlarge your UIView.**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as the person who posted the question. Thanks to the first answer, I had a hint as to what to do. I increased the height of the view by adjusting the frame. This, apparently must be done in code. Once this was done, however, the toolbar at the bottom was no longer visible. So before I adjust the height of the view, I grab the position of the tool bar. Then after adjusting the height of the view, I reset the position of the tool bar. Now all is good.

Comment: Adjusting the frame of what? Scrollview?

Comment: By adjusting the frame of the Frame content view (i.e. the UIView that is inside the frame).